# Getting "Sys.ArgumentException: Value must not be null for Controls and Behaviors. Parameter name: element" in AJAX Control Toolkit

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, internet-explorer, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using AJAX control toolkit accordion on my page. It's working fine on firefox and chrome but gives error on IE.
Below is the code for accordion control :

```
<ATK:Accordion ID="MyAccordion" runat="Server" SelectedIndex="-1" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"
    HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected" ContentCssClass="accordionContent"
    AutoSize="None" FadeTransitions="true" TransitionDuration="250" FramesPerSecond="40"
    RequireOpenedPane="false" SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true">
    <Panes>
        <ATK:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane4" runat="server">
            <Header>
                <asp:Literal ID ="Literal38" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:BF_Resources, SITE_HolidayExceptionAccordian %>"></asp:Literal> 
            </Header>
            <Content>...
```

And below is the error on UI :
[image]

Comment: Please add more information or code so that people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar issue on a different control and thought I would share the solution.

It seems that in my case it was missing a telerik:RadAjaxManager with Ajax settings for the control ID and what LoadingPanel object to use.
If you use the template below and fill in your appropriate objects etc it should resolve the issue.

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" EnableAJAX="true" OnAjaxRequest="RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest" ClientEvents-OnRequestStart="ajaxManager_RequestStart">
     <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadAjaxManager1">
                <UpdatedControls>
                  <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rgControlNameHere" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanelNameHere" />
             </UpdatedControls>
      </telerik:AjaxSetting>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

Hopefully this can help anyone using Telerik controls as well.